# Why does re.sub('.*?', '-', 'abc') return '-a-b-c-' instead of '-------'?

Tags: python, regex

This is the results from python2.7.

```
>>> re.sub('.*?', '-', 'abc')
'-a-b-c-'
```

The results I thought **should** be as follows.

```
>>> re.sub('.*?', '-', 'abc')
'-------'
```

But it's not. Why?

Comment: You've now changed your question quite significantly.  Why do you expect it to produce that result?

Comment: @BrenBarn Because `'.'` matches any character, why does it not replace 'a', 'b' and 'c' to '-' and only replace zero character to '-'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best explanation of this behaviour I know of is from the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) PyPI package, which is intended to *eventually* replace `re` (although it has been this way for a long time now).

> Sometimes it’s not clear how zero-width matches should be handled. For example, should .* match 0 characters directly after matching >0 characters?
>
> Most regex implementations follow the lead of Perl (PCRE), but the re module sometimes doesn’t. The Perl behaviour appears to be the most common (and the re module is sometimes definitely wrong), so in version 1 the regex module follows the Perl behaviour, whereas in version 0 it follows the legacy re behaviour.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> # Version 0 behaviour (like re)
> >>> regex.sub('(?V0).*', 'x', 'test')
> 'x'
> >>> regex.sub('(?V0).*?', '|', 'test')
> '|t|e|s|t|'
>
> # Version 1 behaviour (like Perl)
> >>> regex.sub('(?V1).*', 'x', 'test')
> 'xx'
> >>> regex.sub('(?V1).*?', '|', 'test')
> '|||||||||'
> ```

`(?VX)` sets the version flag in the regex. The second example is what you expect, and is supposedly what PCRE does. Python's `re` is somewhat nonstandard, and is kept as it is probably solely due to backwards compatibility concerns. [I've found an example of something similar](https://bugs.python.org/issue3262) (with `re.split`).

Comment: That's quite different from `re`. But I think `regex` really do the **right** thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you interpreted [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)'s documentation correctly?

> `*?`, `+?`, `??` The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if
>   the RE <.*> is matched against `'<H1>title</H1>'`, it will match the
>   entire string, and not just `'<H1>'`. Adding '?' after the qualifier
>   makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few
>   characters as possible will be matched. Using .*? in the previous
>   expression will match only ''.

Adding a `?` will turn the expression into a non-greedy one.

**Greedy:**

```
re.sub(".*", "-", "abc")
```

**non-Greedy:**

```
re.sub(".*?", "-", "abc")
```

**Update:** FWIW `re.sub` does exactly what it should:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> sub(".*?", "-", "abc")
'-a-b-c-'
>>> sub(".*", "-", "abc")
'-'
```

See @BrenBarn's awesome answer on why you get `-a-b-c-` :)

Here's a visual representation of what's going on:

```
.*?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mOJU8zu1w1xkDvdT)

Answer (score 3):

For your new, edited question:

The `.*?` can match any number of characters, including zero.  So what it does is it matches zero characters at every position in the string: before the "a", between the "a" and "b", etc.  It replaces each of those zero-width matches with a hyphen, giving the result you see.

The regex does not try to match each character one by one; it tries to match at each position in the string.  Your regex allows it to match zero characters.  So it matches zero at each position and moves on to the next.  You seem to be thinking that in a string like "abc" there is one position before the "b", one position "inside" the "b", and one position after "b", but there isn't a position "inside" an individual character.  If it matches zero characters starting before "b", the next thing it tries is to match starting after "b".  There's no way you can get a regex to match seven times in a three-character string, because there are only four positions to match at.

Comment: Since '.' matches any character, why does it not replace 'a', 'b' and 'c' to '-' and only replace zero-width character to '-'?

Comment: @thuzhf: I added a bit to my answer.  `.` *can* match any character, but you allow it to match zero, so it does.  There is no position "inside" an individual character for it to match.  If it finds a match before "b", it then tries to find one after.  If you want it to match the "b", you have to let the regex consume the "b" instead of matching nothing.

Comment: @thuzhf: I don't understand what you're asking there.

Comment: Just ignore that comment. Thanks for you interpretation!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on [Veedrac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30160235/1400768), different implementation has different treatment of zero-width matches in a FindAll (or ReplaceAll) operations. Two behaviors can be observed among different implementations, and Python `re` simply chooses to follow the first line of implementation.

### 1. Always bump along by one character on zero-width match

In Java and JavaScript, zero-width match causes the index to bump along by one character, since staying at the same index will cause an infinite loop in FindAll or ReplaceAll operations.

As a result, output of FindAll operations in such implementation can contain at most 1 match starting at a particular index.

The default Python `re` package probably also follow the same implementation (and it seems to be also the case for Ruby).

### 2. Disallow zero-width match on next match at same index

In PHP, which provides a wrapper over PCRE libreary, zero-width match does **not** cause the index to bump along immediately. Instead, it will set a flag (`PCRE_NOTEMPTY`) requiring the next match (which starts at the same index) to be a non-zero-width match. If the match succeeds, it will bump along by the length of the match (non-zero); otherwise, it bumps along by one character.

<sup>By the way, PCRE library does not provide built-in FindAll or ReplaceAll operation. It is actually provided by PHP wrapper.</sup>

As a result, output of FindAll operations in such implementation can contain up to 2 matches starting at the same index.

Python `regex` package probably follows this line of implementation.

This line of implementation is more complex, since it requires the implementation of FindAll or ReplaceAll to keep an extra state of whether to disallow zero-width match or not. Developer also needs to keep track of this extra flags when they use the low level matching API.